# reference error in mysqlpp

Tags: c++, ld, mysqlpp

as many others I have got the problem to compile a program including mysqlpp.
mysqlpp seems to be installed correctly, the library paths are set correctly in /etc/ld.so.conf also and are known  (so I think):

```
$ sudo ldconfig -p | grep mysql
libmysqlpp.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libmysqlpp.so.3
libmysqlpp.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libmysqlpp.so
libmysqlclient.so.18 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
libmysqlclient.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so
```

But something seems to be wrong, the compiler doesn't find the library of mysqlpp.
Linking-Compiler command:

```
 /usr/bin/c++ -lm -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lmysqlclient -lmysqlpp -o myprogram  myprogram.o
```

Error-Message that the mysqlpp references are missing (beside from many other missing references):

```
/usr/local/include/mysql++/row.h:328: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::Row::at(unsigned long) const'
myprogram.o: In function `mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult::operator=(mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult const&)':
/usr/local/include/mysql++/result.h:252: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult::copy(mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult const&)'
myprogram.o: In function `long mysqlpp::String::do_conv<long>(char const*) const':
/usr/local/include/mysql++/mystring.h:615: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::String::length() const'
/usr/local/include/mysql++/mystring.h:615: undefined reference to `mysqlpp::String::data() const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am at my wit's end. Perhaps somebody of you can help me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker looks for dependencies in reverse order, so you need to put the libraries *after* the object (or source) files on the command line.

```
$ c++ myprogram.o -o myprogram -lm -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lmysqlclient -lmysqlpp
```

Comment: oh my.. such a simple reason! yes, indeed, your hint solved my problem. Thanks!